# regarding the difference, intersection and union of two vectors

Tags: r

I have a csv file, which has two rows, and each row corresponds to a list of words. I read this csv file into a 2*2000 matrix as follows:

```
termlist = as.matrix(read.csv("termlist.csv",sep=",",header=FALSE))
```

Right now, I would like to know the following information for these two rows, the intersection list of the first row and the second row; the remaining list after subtracting this intersection list from the second row.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're looking for `intersect` and `setdiff`:

```
term.intersect <- intersect(termlist[1,], termlist[2,])
term2.diff.term1 <- setdiff(termlist[2, ], termlist[1, ])
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. In fact, I have an extended version of this question. Is there a way for getting the intersection, union of two csv files. I also posted that question with tag R. Thanks.